# MVC 3 Razor treating string within javascript as html

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a javascript function within my cshtml file which builds a table, and adds it to a div on the page using JQuery.

I made a couple of changes recently, and now it seems that visual studio is treating the below as html which needs to be parsed. (Error: Unterminated string literal)

```
footer = footer + "</td></tr></tfoot>";
```

I'm looking to understand why this is happening - as this worked previously, and there are other tags in my function which do not show errors, like the below.

```
var footer = "<tfoot><tr><td colspan='7'>";
```

I can get around it by using the code below instead, but I'd rather find the cause so I can fix this properly.

```
footer = footer + '@Html.Raw("</td></tr></tfoot>")';
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your table building code?

Comment: Wrapping the javascript with the <text> tag might help.

Comment: Could you move the javascript code to an external (.js) file?

Comment: What were the changes that caused the error to appear?

Comment: I have solved the problem in another way. I had: @model dynamic
@{ } brackets around the whole file. I only need this for the very beginning where I work out a path using URL.Content("~path"). I've rearranged the file so the offending part is no longer under these brackets. This is not the whole answer though, it still doesn't explain why the parser is suddenly complaining about this html string in my javascript.

I don't think any of my other html is the problem - it seems to parse the start of the footer tags, all I do is add <a href></a> links in a loop.

Comment: The changes were re-arranging an if, else if, else statement. I rearranged it so that the logic for the else if was swapped with the logic for the if - so it ran in a different order. That's why I was surprised that this error was appearing suddenly.